# DoCmd.OpenReport Asks for values Access07

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007, jet

I have a form that opens a report based on a combo box selection.
Which looks like. [image]

The invoice shipment button opens the report via

`DoCmd.OpenReport "ItemList4", acViewReport, , "ShipRef = " & Me.SRCB`

SRCB is the combo box next to the shipment label.

When clicking the invoice shipment button I always get asked what the parameter value for S100018 is, so obviously it knows what the value is but isn't applying it to the filter when opening the report like so

[image]

How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

I always create a query with a `where` clause that refers back to the `textbox` in the form. Then I build the report on the query, which selects 1 record, and I get my report.

I'l show a quick demo, here is a table named `Persons`:
[image]

Then create a form with a textbox, I named the form `PersonForm`:
[image]

Now creat a `query` that selects everything from the `Persons` table. In the where clause, open the builder, browse to the created form and select the textbox.
[image]

Then we create a very simple `report` with the *report wizard*, based on the `query`.
[image]

Now we go back to our created `form` and add a `button`. In the button, select for the option to open a `report`.

[image]

Now if you open the form in `Form view`, enter the name `Ivo` in my instance. And then click the button.

[image]

Of course you have to adjust the example to your context.

Create a `query` with the data that you need to generate the report. Then add a `where clause` in the `query` to the `list box` where you display your shipment id. Then let the `report` get the **data from the query**.

Comment: This sort of works, however I am not pulling the right information on the report. For example the query pulls every single record for "Item" going to play around with it some more.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the report. It looks like it's accesing a variable called S100018. Is this intended behaviour?

Comment: S100018 is a field on the report. It's the field I want the report to be filtered by. So in theory you select S100018 or perhaps s100019 from t he combo box then click invoice shipment then the report will be filtered by that "Shipment"

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that it was not sending the filter argument as a string

it should be as such
 `DoCmd.OpenReport "ItemList4", acViewReport, , "ShipRef = '" & Me.SRCB & "'"`